# After update xcode 9 native camera fie_uri not working

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, xcode9

After I update to xcode 9 and build the app, the native camera plugin I used, the preview img [src]= filePath was become blank, and I change it to base64 data, the data is empty. (i.e. Android is working fine). Anyonr know what happen?

```
    let cameraOptions = {
      sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,      
      quality: 100,
      targetWidth: 600,
      targetHeight: 600,
      encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,      
      correctOrientation: true
    }

    this.camera.getPicture(cameraOptions)
    .then(file_uri => {
          this.imageSrc = file_uri;
    },
    err => console.log(err));
```

html:

```
<img (tap)="openGallery()"  [src]="imageSrc"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is known issue on `iOS 11`.

You can try this:

```
ionic cordova plugin rm camera
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera  --variable CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION="your usage message" --variable PHOTOLIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION="your usage message"
```

You can read more about [**this issue here**](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native/issues/2020).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have read this post before I post this issue. I have tried the command already, but the problem still exist. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Do I need to delete the node_modules and npm install again?

Comment: Yes, You need to do that too.

Comment: Hi, I have tried again, I confirmed that is not working. And My iphone is 10.3.1, not 11. And this problem is occur after I update xcode from 8 to 9.

Comment: OK, Then the best option here is open a new issue with minimal working git project of your app here: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/new